# identity jumped by 10000 in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I am using godaddy shared hosting & SQL Server. There are two tables (usertbl, patienttble) with primary key auto-incremented by 1. I am using LINQ to SQL classes for DB operation.

Problem is after adding uid (primary key from usertbl) as 1443, SQL Server added next row uid as **11443** and at the same operation in patienttble previous id was 1439, it added next row and id was **11439**. I am not able to understand how this happen. Before and after this problem happen id in both the table was incremented by 1 properly.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not guarantee that there are no gaps in identity fields, and that's what [Books online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) also tells you:

> **Consecutive values after server restart or other failures** –SQL Server
>   might cache identity values for performance reasons and some of the
>   assigned values can be lost during a database failure or server
>   restart. This can result in gaps in the identity value upon insert. If
>   gaps are not acceptable then the application should use its own
>   mechanism to generate key values. Using a sequence generator with the
>   NOCACHE option can limit the gaps to transactions that are never
>   committed.

Like mentioned above, using SEQUENCES with NOCACHE could be good enough alternative.